# How to use position of relative?

Tags: css

I have created a todo-apps with js but I have one problem :  my button doesn’t move when I add some other task to do While I give it a position of relative. This is my CSS code:

```
button {
  border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;

}
```

This is my HTML code

```
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." id="Name">
    <input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add Item" />
    <div class="choices">
      <p id="p"></p>

    <button id="btn" type="submit"> Clear Items</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a picture : [image: picture of the result]

Comment: It's relative to it's parent so you'll need top/bottom/right/left positions for it to be moved from it's normal position.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning

Comment: your button doesn’t "move" or  "remove" when you add other task???

Comment: @Gad he doesn't move : he just move the first time when I add one task but when I add 2 task he doesn't move

Comment: For us to understand if things are working correctly, you will need to show your 'insertion' Javascript code as well. Right now we can only assume it works alright....[reprex].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do some reading on 'stacking context' (e.g. [MDN: The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and [MDN: Stacking without the z-index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)) as it is important to understand what layering elements (or 'stacking') in a document encompasses.

For your problem, remember this: a container holding 1 to N child elements (in your case '.choices' with 1 button) has to be `position: relative` and its child elements `position: absolute` with (optionally) their positioning values set (`top, right,left,bottom`).

So, when you want the 'Clear Items' button to stick to the bottom of the TODO-list you need at least:

```
.choices {
    position: relative; /* makes child elements move relative to this parent */
}

button {
    position: absolute; /* move this element absolute within parent */
    bottom: 0.5rem;     /* position just above parent bottom */
}
```

**The example snippet:**

```css
.choices {
    position: relative;     /* makes child elements move relative to this parent */

    /* DEMO */
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem; /* create some bottom space below button */
    background-color: Linen;
}

#btn {
    position: absolute; /* move this element absolute within parent */
    bottom: 0.5rem;     /* position just above parent bottom */

    border-radius: 5px;

    /* to horizontally center within parent */
    left: 50%;                   /* move child to center of parent */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* move half size of child back */
}
```

```html
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." id="Name">
    <input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add Item" />

    <div class="choices">
        <p id="p"></p>
        <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

        <button id="btn" type="submit">Clear Items</button>
    </div>
```

**HOWEVER**

In your construction you made the 'Clear Items' button part of the javascript output container, which is logically incorrect. 'action buttons' are not part of the content itself and need their own container (obviously they can be over/under content, but are not part of the content, your 'TODO-items', itself).

By having split the functionality (input, output, actions) it now no longer matters how you modify the 'output' with Javascript, the 'actions' stay below the content.

Below an example snippet showing how I would structure your TODO panel with 'flexbox layout'.

Generic code (at least required):

```
.flexbox-panel {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.user-input         { ... }          /* user entry field and button */
.js-todo-output     { flex-grow: 1 } /* the TODO-items */
user-action-buttons { ... }          /* the action button(s) */
```

This way it does not matter how many items there are in the list, the action button stays below them.

**Second snippet with 'Flexbox Layout' alternative:**

```css
.flexbox-panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.flexbox-panel>* {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem; /* some nice inner spacing */
}

.user-input          {  }               /* user entry field and button */
.js-todo-output      { flex-grow: 1 }   /* the TODO-items */
.user-action-buttons {  }               /* the action button(s) */

.js-todo-output,
.user-action-buttons { background-color: Linen; }

.act-button          { display: block; margin: 0 auto }
/* default is 'inline', needs to be 'block' for margin to work */

/* for easy debugging (put in <body>) */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed }

/**************************/
/* preferred global rules */
/**************************/
html,body               { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; max-width: 100% }
*::before,*::after, *   { box-sizing: inherit }

body {
    margin: 0; /* remove HTML default body spacing */

/*
    responsive page padding with 'linear equation y=mx+b'
    p1(320,32) p2(1920, 72) => 0.025x + 24
    p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 

    On an  320px display the T/B space is 32px and the L/R space   8px
    On an 1920px display the T/B space is 72px and the L/R space 320px
    
    All other values for all other display sizes are calculated.

    math reference:  https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html
*/
    padding: calc(2.5vh + 24px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}
```

```html
<body outlines="0">
    <div class="flexbox-panel">
        <h1>To Do List with flexbox</h1>
        <div class="user-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." id="Name">
            <input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add Item" />
        </div>
        <div class="js-todo-output">
            <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="user-action-buttons">
            <button class="act-button" type="submit">Clear Items</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EXTRA**

I have inserted a few of my preferred global rules into the second snippet (commonly accepted defaults) and also show how you can use some math to create 'responsive sizing' in your webpage (with math reference [MathIsFun: equation of a straight line](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html)).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you set position related to 'choices' class.

Set position related to HTML page.

Comment: no it doesn't work but I have create a simple js function to increase the Margin by 50px each time the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

you must also provide an offset with:

```
top: 5px;
```

for example. Other attributes can be : bottom, right, left.

Comment: if you use this : 
button {
  border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
right: 200px;
}

it doesn't do nothing ?

Comment: I add a picture to see the result

Answer (score 0):

button move out the div.choices
And wrap the button in another div.